# Confirmation on my Understanding of Beginning Android Concept (Using Multiple Activities)

Tags: java, android, android-intent, reflection

I am a beginner at android development, and have reached the end of [Building your First App](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/index.html). Before I move on, I would like to **confirm and validate my understanding of using multiple activities and communicating from one activity to another**.

```
/** Called when the user clicks the Send button */
public void sendMessage(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
    EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
    String message = editText.getText().toString();
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

***1)*** Is my understanding correct that the second paramater in the constructor for Intent (`Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class)`) serves as a reference for `startActivity(...)` and reflection is used to call the method `onCreate()` in the class `DisplayMessageActivity` since the class `DisplayMessageActivity` was given as a class object?

***2)*** What is the use of the first paramater (the context one in the constructor)? (Basically how does Android use the first parameter, a brief description please, to start the activity)?

***3)*** As seen in the tutorial, last part of building your first app, it advises me to declare a variable as such: (`public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "me.marshac.myfirstapp.MESSAGE";`). I know the purpose of this declaration and initialization, but why don't I have to specify the full package name (`me.marshac.myfirstapp. (...) .MESSAGE`) and where is the MESSAGE variable coming from? The only two variables similar to that are both local variables in sendMessage() and the other activity's onCreate(), but they are different case and local?

I am sorry for the very in-depth inquiries, I want to establish a firm understanding of the beginner concepts before I move on to intermediate/advanced ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Yes. I think that's what is happening behind the scenes. If you want to know exactly how they did it, you can go to read the Android OS source code. It is open source, you know. Just Google it!

2) Android uses a stack for storing activities. When you first started your app, it's like this:

```
MyActivity
```

Then when you start another activity, a new activity object is pushed onto the stack

```
DisplayMessageActivity
MyActivity
```

When you tap the back button, an activity from the stack is popped.

If you didn't give `this` as the parameter, how would the OS know where to push the new activity onto?

3) I think this is just a convention of some kind. I usually use simple names like `message`, and it works! It's similar to asking why should I name a class in PascalCase and a local variable in camelCase?

Comment: For your answers on #1 and #2, brief, yet descriptive, thank you :) Regarding #3, I think you misunderstood me. From my thinking EXTRA_MESSAGE is referencing a variable path, yet the full path isn't present (missing class name). Why is this? And what is it referencing? It seems like a variable named MESSAGE, but there are no variables named MESSAGE (at least with that capitalization, which is important. Still marking this as accepted, however, it explained 2/3 of the original post, so once again thanks :D

Comment: @MarDev `EXTRA_MESSAGE` is not referencing a variable or a class. It acts like a key for you to get back the message you sent in the other activity, just like a `HashMap` kind of thing. It's just personal preferences, really. These things don't matter that much.

Comment: Thanks, I understand it much more now, it acts like a link or communication wire between the two activities.